# How to include firebase snapshot key value? [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Please anyone who would show me how to include the snapshot key value along with children value that I already append to my array (forgot to include it and now remember I have to) ... aside from that something really I couldn't understand when I tried to solve my own issue, by testing the value first by using this method:  `print(rooms.popFirst().key!)` half of my database values got `nil` value ?!! and if I don't include that method everything works fine anyways if you can't imagine that nonetheless I really wish your suggestion or advice for getting all data with their own key value... 
This is my code so far:

```
Database.database().reference().child("rooms").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print()

        var rooms = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]

        for(_,value) in rooms  {

            if (rooms.popFirst()?.key) != nil{

                let title = value["title"] as? String
                let description = value["description"] as? String
                let roomPictureUrl = value["Room Picture"] as? String
                let longitude = value["Longtitude"] as? String
                let latitude = value["Latitude"] as? String
                let dateFrom = value["Date From"] as? String
                let dateTo = value["Date To"] as? String
                let owner = value["Owner"] as? String

                let myRooms = Room(roomID: "XXX",title: title!, description: description!, roomPicutreURL: roomPictureUrl!, longitude: longitude!, latitude: latitude!, dateFrom: dateFrom!, dateTo: dateTo!, owner: owner!)

                //print(rooms.popFirst()?.key)
                self.rooms.append(myRooms)
                self.tableView.reloadData()



            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Database.database().reference().child("rooms").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    var rooms = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
    let roomKeys = Array(rooms.keys)

    for roomKey in roomKeys  {

            guard

                let value = rooms[roomKey] as? [String:AnyObject]

            else
            {
                 continue
            }

            let title = value["title"] as? String
            let description = value["description"] as? String
            let roomPictureUrl = value["Room Picture"] as? String
            let longitude = value["Longtitude"] as? String
            let latitude = value["Latitude"] as? String
            let dateFrom = value["Date From"] as? String
            let dateTo = value["Date To"] as? String
            let owner = value["Owner"] as? String

            let myRooms = Room(roomID: "XXX",title: title!, description: description!, roomPicutreURL: roomPictureUrl!, longitude: longitude!, latitude: latitude!, dateFrom: dateFrom!, dateTo: dateTo!, owner: owner!)

            print(roomKey)
            self.rooms.append(myRooms)
            self.tableView.reloadData()



        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the key from snapshot you can use following lines of code it will give you result like `-> Kqwewsds12 -> your child Details`

```
let dictValues = [String](snapshot.keys)

            print(dictValues[0]) //Output -- Kqwewsds12
```